# Favorites tab scrolls too far in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, bookmarks

In the iOS app, if you're able to scroll down on the favorites tab, you're able to scroll much farther than you should be able to:

> [image]

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: I can repro this on 1.6.3.6 but not on 1.6.4 (beta) so I guess this has already been fixed